# Map function rendering all images on a component rather than one image per component

Tags: reactjs

I am making an external API call to my database which holds URL's to images stored in firebase. When I map the array it is rendering all six images on each element rather than one per element like I want. My code is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';

import Isp from '../components/Isp';
import SearchGroup from '../components/SearchGroup';
import Seek from '../components/Seek';

import plus from '../images/icon_plus.png';
import minus from '../images/icon_minus.png';

const GET_ALL_LINKS = gql`
  {
    allLinks {
      category
      imageLink
    }
  }
`;

const Section = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_ALL_LINKS);

  const categories = data && data.allLinks.map(link => link.category);
  const allCategories =
    categories &&
    categories.filter((item, index) => categories.indexOf(item) === index);

  const images = data && data.allLinks.map(image => image.imageLink);
  const allImages =
    images && images.filter((item, index) => images.indexOf(item) === index);
  console.log(allImages);

  return (
    <div>
      {allCategories &&
        allCategories.map(category => (
          <ul key={category} className='searchmenu'>
            <Collapsible
              trigger={
                <span className={`outer-span`}>
                  {allImages &&
                    allImages.map(image => (
                      <img src={image} alt='' key={image} />
                    ))}
                  {category}
                  <span
                    className='inner-span'
                    style={{
                      backgroundImage: `url(${plus})`,
                      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                      border: 'none',
                      float: 'right'
                    }}
                  ></span>
                </span>
              }
              triggerWhenOpen={
                <span className={`outer-span`}>
                  {allImages &&
                    allImages.map(image => (
                      <img src={image} alt='' key={image} />
                    ))}
                  {category}
                  <span
                    className='inner-span'
                    style={{
                      backgroundImage: `url(${minus})`,
                      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                      border: 'none',
                      float: 'right'
                    }}
                  ></span>
                </span>
              }
            >
              <Isp category={category} />
              <SearchGroup category={category} />
              <Seek category={category} />
            </Collapsible>
          </ul>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Section;
```

and here is how it renders on the screen.

[image]

Ideally I would like to get one unique image per category.

UPDATE WITH DATA SETS:
allCategories:
[image: allCategories]

allImages:
[image: allImages]

Comment: Can you provide the sample data for data.allLinks?

Comment: Did you actually intend to render `allImages` mapping *outside* the `allCategories` mapping? NM, I see you want only one of the images for each category. Have you tried merging the images into your categories array? Is there a 1-to-1 relationship between images and categories?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you make a map allCategories

`allCategories.map(category => (`

and then you make a loop for allImages

`allImages.map(image => (`

thus all the images are showing in all the category.

but if you make some condition instead of using the second loop like get the image for the following category and display it without any loop. I think this will resolve your issue

and if you can provide the dataset of allCategories array and allImages array i can help you further.

Comment: @Rajseh I updated my original post with the data sets. I had to do a screenshot as they are data calls from my API. Thanks.

Comment: @timbo245 i can see that there are 6 category and 6 images but no matching criteria, i assume you want to show the item in the order of category then you can show the image like

add another property here

`allCategories.map((category,index) => (`
and add the index here
`allImages[index]`

to show the first image to first category and second image to second category